# Creating a Directory on IOS

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

My app creates a data directory when installed. At runtime I need to create subdirectories.

path is the path to the data directory. If do:

```
  NSArray *temp =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error] ;
```

I get no error and a list of files.

If I move on and do:

```
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYSUBDIR"] ;
bool status = [fm createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error] ;
```

I get this error:

> (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1702609c0  . . . NSUnderlyingError=0x170045850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"

Any ideas why I cannot create a subdirectory?

0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-

Let me broaden the question. I have an app that new ships data through the app. As this is getting too large, I would like to shift to in-app purchase. I would like the app to be transparent in how it deals with the two types of data.

If I cannot create a directory where in the area where the app ships data and I cannot ship data in the documents directory where I can create new directories, how can I transparently handle the different in locations for the data?

It appears the symbolic links from the data directory to the bundle do not work either.

Comment: What is path? Is it a path in resource bundle?

Comment: Print `path`. What do you get?

Comment: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D35BDB5D-3E67-4DA4-A398-909164ED0408/TestAPP/RecordData

Comment: @user3344003: You can't modify the app bundle. You can create files and folders at run-time only in the document directory not on app bundle

Comment: Is it possible to add files at build time to the documents directory?

Comment: @user3344003 No, you must create the folders at runtime.